# scripting sprocs, tables, views, functions, triggers as individual files

Tags: sql-server

I would like to use github to version control the main objects in my SQL Server 2008 database. I have searched and read many articles and different approaches. There are various utility programs, .NET code, vbscripts, etc. and  I realize I can use the "Generate Scripts wizard" from Management Studio.

However, what I would like to do is run a sql script that will do all this for me in one "swoop", and I've found something that is very close: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2008/10/24/How-to-script-out-all-your-objects-one-per-file.aspx

It works fast, efficient and even creates a nice folder structure to put each individual file into. One thing that's really handy is that its easy to modify to only select objects with a certain prefix only. It is almost perfect!

So in a perfect world I would love some help to get the script to do two more things:

1. include tables to be scripted
2. figure out how it will write the files to my local machine even though i'm connecting from my local machine to a remote machine.

As I said, this script is great minus the two issues above that would solve all my issues. It would then make it easy to run the script after a workday, have it generate each object as a file into a folder on my local machine that is watched by git, then check differences into github.

Hope this question is understandable :)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Looks more like a feature request than a question

Comment: I guess you could say so - is this the wrong place for this type of "question" or request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check out red-gate sql server source control? It fits right into SSMS, and is a breeze to use.... we use it and it works perfectly....

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/

Comment: I will try it out - I was hoping for a solution without installs of more software, upgrades, config, etc. But thanks for pointing them out.

Comment: Why rebuild the wheel :) Its actually an install on the local machine - requires nothing on the server... you just need to provide it a source control that it can use... and it works with git, I think...